# Metro style app tutorial using C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Curently I am doing the tutorial about metro applications from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380).

```
namespace MetroTutorial
{
    partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetFeedAsync("http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/atom.aspx");
        }

        private async Task GetFeedAsync(string feedUriString)
        {
            // using Windows.Web.Syndication;
            SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
            Uri feedUri = new Uri(feedUriString);

            try
            {
                SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri);
                FeedData feedData = new FeedData();
                feedData.Title = feed.Title.Text;

                foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
                {
                    FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
                    feedItem.Title = item.Title.Text;
                    feedItem.PubDate = item.PublishedDate.DateTime;
                    feedItem.Author = item.Authors[0].Name.ToString();
                    if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Atom10)
                    {
                        feedItem.Content = item.Content.Text;
                    }
                    else if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Rss20)
                    {
                        feedItem.Content = item.Summary.Text;
                    }
                    feedData.Items.Add(feedItem);
                }
                this.DataContext = feedData;
                ItemListView.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log Error.
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public class FeedData
    {
        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FeedItem> _Items = new ObservableCollection<FeedItem>();
        public ObservableCollection<FeedItem> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Items;
            }
        } 
    }

    public class FeedItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I can't make it work, when I run it, it just opens the window with a clock and thats it.

Do I need to set something in XAML to the ListView, if yes what exactly ?

Comment: Does `GetFeedAsync()` ever run to completion?  You might want to set some breakpoints or write to the log to check if it runs and how far it runs as expected.

Comment: Yes I cheked that, it runs to completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem was that my ListView was not visible, I had to enlarge that square that appeared when you add the List.

Then I had to set:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
DisplayMemberPath="Title"
```

Thats it.